# Managing full SQL transaction in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Referring to this, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm

How the transactions are managed into the MySQL database.

My concern is, I have an application that is writing a few queries similar to the given link for completing a full transaction. I want to ensure that it always write correct & full transaction for final save & doesn't write incomplete transaction into SQL in case of power failure or some other circumstances to ensure the correctness of the transaction.

Just want to know how it can be implemented into MySQL db.

Comment: If you want your database to be resilient against power failure, use an UPS.

Comment: Its not about just power failure, I understand all this and have this kind of setup for 100% power uptime. The requirements are such that I can not allow to have incomplete transaction into db.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*incomplete transaction*"? After a transaction has ended it is **never** incomplete. That is the whole purpose of a transaction.

Comment: @Krunal If you're using SQL transactions at all, you get the guarantee that the transaction will only be "written to the database" once the client commits the transaction. (Now, the entire preceeding sentence is full of lies, but it's a good enough approximation. E.g. partially complete transactions may, in fact, be written to disk, and the changes in them are made unavailable to other transactions. I recommend hitting a database systems textbook for the nitty gritty details of transaction isolation, concurrency anomalies, and how transactions are implemented.)

Comment: Also, in the case of power failure, what might happen is that transactions reported as committed to the client are lost: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#durability_problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are using a transactional storage engine, such an InnoDB.
Next, make sure you understand [the statements that cause implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html).

[Read documentation on transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html)

Comment: I have found a way to implement the same with JTA (Java Transactions API) as well.